# 64 bit operations

Tags: c

I'm writing code for a primality testing function that handles long long int's.Do I have to use special operators for such large numbers?Is there any documentation concerning large number manipulation in C?I'm using the gnu standard library.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long long is new in C99, though many compilers have supported that as an extension before that.

With gcc a long long is 64 bits, you can use it like any other integer type, nothing special is required.

There's a couple of things to be aware of though, integer constants in the source code needs the LL suffix (or LLU if it's unsigned, e.g. you have to do

```
long long foo = 123412341234123LL;
```

and not

```
long long foo = 123412341234123;
```

Similarly, for outputting a long long with the printf family, you have to use the conversion specifier "%lld" instead of "%d" or "%ld" (or "%llu" if it's unsigned), e.g.

```
printf("foo = %lld",foo);
```

There's some docs about long long in gcc [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html)

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to do anything special. You handle a `long long int` just the same way as you would handle a `int`. Just beware of overflows, as with every native integer type.

Answer (score 3):

If long long ints are supported by your compiler you don't have to do any 'special' kind of stuff. If your processor doesn't support 64-bit types (probably 32-bit-processor then) the compiler will emulate that feature by using sequences of assembly code that breaks up the 64-bit operations into 32-bit ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler supports `long long int`, it works with standard operators.

By the way, `long long int` is 128 bits on 64-bit unices (where `long` alone is 64 bits). Use `int64_t` from `<stdint.h>` if you need 64-bits on all platforms. This does not apply to 64-bit windows, where `long` is still 32 bits and `long long` is 64 bits.

Comment: `long long` is 64-bit on 64-bit Linux, at least on common archs. Not sure about other Unices or ugly legacy stuff like Alpha, Sparc, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are just handling `long long int` you don't need anything special as long as your compiler supports it. Take care of overflows while adding and multiplying two `long long int`s

For handling very large numbers(range much greater than that of `long long int`) have a look at [GNU MP BigNum Library](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it might be that GMP is generally disliked on SO as the perfect example of bad library code. One of its worst offenses is unconditionally `abort()`ing the caller if it runs out of memory rather than reporting the error back and providing a way for the caller to recover. This makes it impossible to use as part of any high-reliability program, and thus impossible to use in any library that might be used as part of a high-reliability program.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the GMP library: http://gmplib.org/